# Recursion with self-calling

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

Good morning/day/night, SO community. Here's a problem I bumped into several days ago and still got no answer to it.

I have a dictionary:

```
maindict = {
1Class: [2Class, 3Class],
2Class: [2-1Class, 2-2Class, 2-3Class],
3Class: [3-1Class],
2-1Class: [],
2-2Class: [2-2-1Class]
}
```

and so on.

I also know which class is main, for example it would be 1Class. I save it in:
    mainclass = (0, 1Class)

I have a function, that finds the subclasses in maindict for given class, and returns a dictionary of tuples:

```
def getSubClass(maindict, class):
    MAGIC HERE
    return result
```

The result for 
    getSubClass(maindict, mainclass)
would be list with tuples:

> [(1-1, 2Class), (1-2, 3Class)]

The problem is that I need to iterate over all classes and get subclasses for each class. Some classes don't have subclasses, some do. So for test I did this:

```
b = getSubClass(maindict, mainclass)
c = getSubClass(maindict, b)
d = getSubClass(maindict, c)
e = getSubClass(maindict, d)
f = getSubClass(maindict, e)
g = getSubClass(maindict, f)
h = getSubClass(maindict, g)
i = getSubClass(maindict, h)
```

and 'i' was empty, which means that I gathered all classes. I also appended every c, d and so on to dict and verified that the output is right.

Now all I need to do is to write recursive function of manual script I did, but I just stuck here.

Comment: it seams work for `loop`, not for recursion.

Comment: All the names you're using in your example dictionary are invalid (they start with numbers and some contain hyphens). This makes it hard to tell exactly what those names are supposed to represent. Are all the `WhateverClass` objects actual classes? Is this some kind of inheritance diagramming task? Or are they strings, and you've left out the quotation marks?

Comment: I'm sorry name definition confused you. I meant to write Class1/Class2 and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems simple enough. If what you want in the end is a list `[b,c,d,e,f,g,h]`, then you have to edit your `getSubClass` function as follows:

```
def getSubClass(maindict, class, all_subclasses):
    if not class:
        #class is an empty tuple here
        return None
    MAGIC HERE

    # This will append the tuples in result to all_subclasses
    all_subclasses += result

    # Recursively calls getSubClass using the result computed
    # in the current function call.
    # If result is an empty tuple, then nothing will be added
    # to the all_subclasses list in the recursive call made
    getSubClass(maindict, result, all_subclasses)
    return result
```

On calling the function as:

```
all_subclasses = []
getSubClass(maindict, mainclass, [])
```

All subclass-tuples will appear in the `all_subclasses` list

Comment: Thank you. I'll just leave some additions below:
`if not class: return all_subclasses`
`else: return getSubClass(maindict, result, all_subclasses)`